# basic async call on @click event in template vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to set data of a vue.js component with a button template and @click event.
This event call a method component which call a async function with promise.

When I click on my button the result of paragraph tag html appear correctly but in a same time it generated a error into my inspector browser electron like this :

> vue.runtime.esm.js:620 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: foo.then(...).bind is not a function"
> found in
> --->  at src/views/TestDb.vue
>  at src/App.vue

*Very strange to understand why throw error and in same time do the job....*

I now the trick of copy the context this into another variable and call this variable for change data component but it seems to be not advise by esLint process analyse file. It exist a specific rule just for that.

**How can work of basic async promise for change data with a click button template on vuejs ?**

This is my component file :

```
<template>

    <div id="testDb">
        <Menu />
        <h2>Test DB operation</h2>
        <b-button @click="createOperation">create Operation</b-button>
        <p style="background-color: white">{{ returnValue1 }}</p>
    </div>

</template>

<script>

import Menu              from "@/components/Menu";
import ConnectionManager from '../service/ConnectionManager'

export default
{
    name: "TestDb",
    components:
    {
        Menu
    },
    data: function()
    {
        return {
            alert: null,
            returnValue1: "beer"
        }
    },
    methods:
    {
        createOperation: function ()
        {
            const connectionManager = new ConnectionManager()
            let foo = connectionManager.insert('operation')
            foo.then(() => {
                this.returnValue1 = "bar"
            }).bind(this)
        },
    }
}

</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

    @import './src/assets/scss/main';

</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using an arrow function there's no need to add `bind(this)` :

```
 foo.then(() => {
                this.returnValue1 = "bar"
            })
```

or

```
 foo.then(function(){
                this.returnValue1 = "bar"
            }.bind(this))
```

Comment: OK i search many others thing but not about arrow function. Thank you for your very speed response. I confirm that's work well. Perhaps this little issue help others.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `bind` ' the arrow function already did the binding.

```
foo.then(() => {
                this.returnValue1 = "bar"
            })
```

**FYI**

You could have done this before

```
foo.then(() => {
                this.returnValue1 = "bar"
            }.bind(this))
```